# get row indexes from grid using dataView

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

I am working on **SlickGrid batch edit** and I found a useful pluging [here](http://danny-sg.github.io/slickgrid-spreadsheet-plugins/examples/example-2-everything.htm)

This plugin is nice, but I stuck up in a position. I want to get the selected row indexes on clicking a button that I added on the page... here is the code I used to get the `selected row indexes` in my another example, and the code is working there.

```
var selectedIndexes = [];
$("#btn").click(function(){
   // Empty all the array
     while (selectedIndexes.length) { selectedIndexes.pop(); }
   // get the selected row indexes
   selectedIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows();
   alert(selectedIndexes); 
});
```

but here I can't get the `selected row indexes` with the code because here the grid is initiallized by **dataView**

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#grid", dataView, columns, options);
```

So basically I have to get the selected row indexed using **dataView**

please suggest me how can I get the `selected row indexes` using **dataView** when clicking on the button.

Thank you

Comment: `grid` should be defined at global level. after doing this this variable will be available in your `click` handler.

Comment: thanks for your reply. **grid** is already defined at global level

Comment: Can you give us a working JSFiddle?